# Does "who are naked" mean "who are very poor"?

Tags: phrase-meaning

"Naked" means "being without clothing" - so I guess "who are naked" means "who are very poor".  Am I on the right track?

> Pope Francis tweeted 1m ago:

> Everyone is called to contribute with courage and determination to the respect for the fundamental rights of every person, especially the "invisible": of the many who are hungry and thirsty, **who are naked**, sick, outcast or imprisoned.

Comment: This may be opinion but the Pope could have meant they don't only have no clothes, but they have **nothing**.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This is typical Biblical language: when all these adjectives are used together, we are encouraged to think of the needy in general. It's not so much about specific naked people. So, your interpretation is pretty good.

Typical examples:

> I was naked and you clothed Me; I was sick and you visited Me; I was
> in prison and you came to Me.’ (Matthew 25:36)
>
> Is it not to share your bread with the hungry, And that you bring to
> your house the poor who are cast out; When you see the naked, that you
> cover him, And not hide yourself from your own flesh? (Isaiah 58:7)

Comment: Yes, presumably the Biblical reference is to people too poor to have more than minimal clothing, rather than being literally naked.

Comment: @KateBunting I have seen someone so poor they were literally naked.

Comment: @LorenPechtel whereas I have seen people being rich enough to afford vacations in an exclusive nudist camp. Or even people trying to get rich by being naked

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen : indeed, context is everything.

Comment: The fact that this question and answer have been so popular suggests that people will look at anything vaguely titillating! Fair enough.

Comment: Can we maybe imply that back in biblical times when this was written, it was more common for people to be literally so poor they can't afford even basic minimal clothing?  Nowadays, even homeless people can easily get free clothing from various charities, but maybe that wasn't the case back in the day?

Comment: I suppose that could be the case, but I still think it's more metaphorical. I'm sure rags couldn't have been absolutely impossible to come by. Also, I'm guessing complete nakedness was religiously or otherwise morally proscribed.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman At this point it becomes a question for [Hermeneutics.SE], but the original Greek is γυμνός (gymnos), which can mean nude but can also mean stripped down or wearing minimal clothing. Similarly in Old English, *naked* could mean "wearing only an undergarment," a meaning that persisted through at least the 18th century. Like many Biblical words and phrases, however, the usage became fixed despite the everyday meaning of the words shifting.

Comment: @choster : comparing historical fashion to the modern one, if someone from the 19th century was transported to our modern times and see people in T-shirts and shorts walking around, he would wonder why people walk around on the street in their underwear. Someone from the 18th century would then say "why are they walking around naked?"

Comment: It's also worth noting that the climate in most of the locations depicted in the Bible is and has always been on the hot side, so you could get by with far less clothing that you'd need in colder climates.